# How to fix C3867 (non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

ALL,

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void Func()
    {
        if( my_pointer == my_vector.at( [my_vector.size() - 1] ) )
        {
        }
    }
    Bar *my_pointer;
    std::vector<Bar *> my_vector;
};
```

I got an error:

```
error C3867: 'std::vector<Bar *,std::allocator<_Ty>>::at': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
```

What am I doing wrong?

Basically I want to see if my pointer is the last element of the vector...

Comment: @AlexF, I now feel like an idiot. Thank you. ;-)

Comment: `my_vector.back()` is a more concise way to get the last item. You do want to be sure the vector is not empty first though.